# Show that A/B is regular.

Tags: automata, finite-automata

> Let $A/B = \left\{w\mid wx \in A\text{ for some }x\in B\right\}$.
>
> Show that if $A$ is regular and $B$ is any language, then $A/B $  is regular.

My understanding is that we know only about $A$ which is regular but $B$ can be any language (may be non regular). $w$ string is our input. We are checking for existence of a string $x\in B$ such that $wx\in A$.

As I know two non-regular languages can also be concatenated to produce a regular language, so how is this question valid?

Is it like this? As $x$ is just a string which will be finite, so its regular (confused here also). Even if $x$ is regular, because the concatenation of a non regular and regular can also give regular language. So how can we say $w$ will also be regular?

Please clarify.

Comment: **Tip:** use `\in` for $\in$ and `\mid` for $\mid$.

Comment: @FrenzyLi Thanks for the edit.. I am bit naive in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Start with a DFA $M=\langle Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,F\rangle$ for $A$, where the alphabet $\Sigma$ is the union of the alphabets for $A$ and $B$. Let $\bar\delta:Q\times\Sigma^*\to Q$ be the extended transition function: $\bar\delta(q,w)=q'$ if $M$ goes to state $q'$ when it starts in state $q$ and reads the word $w$.

To get a DFA for $A/B$ you need only modify $F$, the set of acceptor (final) states. Change it to

$$F'=\left\{q\in Q:\exists x\in B\,\left(\bar\delta(q,x)\in F\right)\right\}$$

I’ll leave it to you to show that this works.

Comment: Thanks for showing how to implement :) I too had got this idea from internet. But my doubt is different and bit logical. x is any string accepted by B. when we are doing concatenation of "w" (unknown language) with B(let it be non regular) then our result is regular. But we know that  concatenation of two non regular languages can also give regular. Then why we are proving "w" is regular? It can be non regular too. Hope you got my doubt.

Comment: @ViX28: The fact that the concatenation of two non-regular languages can be regular is irrelevant. It’s possible that there is some non-regular language $L$ such that $LB=A$; here we’re just proving that there is always a regular language $L$, namely $A/B$, such that $wB\cap A\ne\varnothing$ for each $w\in L$. This does not say that $LB=A$.

Comment: Thats what needed. You can read mind. Great _/\_  thanks :)

Comment: @ViX28: You’re welcome.

Comment: But $\Sigma^*$ is infinite, so the resulting automata is not finite.

Comment: @MaudPieTheRocktorate: (Apparently your comment was posted during one of my vacations from MSE.) The cardinality of $\Sigma^*$ is irrelevant: $\Sigma^*$ is infinite for *every* language that has at least one non-empty word. What matters is that $Q$ is finite.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong, but I believe that $B$ should also be a regular language.

We are only given $w$ as the input for the DFA of the language $A/B$ and not $wx$. So if B is possibly be turing- undecidable and we would have no way to figure out what is the appropriate suffix $x$ such that $wx$ belongs to $A$ and $x$ belongs to $B$.